# XSLT collection() not working on html-files

Tags: html, xslt

For some reason, `collection()` won't work on HTML files, it's not fetching anything. Yet it works with XML files.

Do you have any clues?

```
<xsl:for-each select="collection('./foldername?select=*.html')//title">       
  <div>
      <xsl:attribute name='value'><xsl:value-of select='//title' /></xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//title"/>
  </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML is not XML. A file can be perfectly valid HTML and not valid XML.

Make sure all your HTML files are valid XML.